# git rebase in multibranch scenario

Tags: git-rebase

I have a situation where I've got a release candidate branch for our currently "frozen" release candidate, a master branch (branched from release candidate) for the most current stable work, and a topic branch (branched from master) for a little expermientation that I'm working on.  Master is currently at the same commit as the release candidate.

If the release candidate moves forward a few commits, is there any functional difference between rebasing master onto release and topic onto release vs master onto release and topic onto master?  Do the refs change and if so if there a reason to prefer one over the other?

I should clarify that this repo is for my own local source control - our team uses a different SCM, so I don't have to worry about fracking things up for anyone else - I'm the only one who ever commits to this repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but generally

```
git checkout a; git rebase c; git checkout b; git rebase c;
```

will result in a tree like this:

```
--c----a
  +----b
```

whereas

```
git checkout a; git rebase c; git checkout b; git rebase a;
```

will result in a tree like this:

```
--c----a----b
```

My suggestion is: just try to picture in your head what you would like the resulting tree to look like and read the examples on the `git-rebase` man page.

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 stages (corresponding branches)

1. Testing (master), less sensitive branch
2. Staging (staging), moderately sensitive branch
3. Production (production), Most sensitive branch
4. We also have individual branches for each feature we implement (least sensitive branch)

Here is how we resolve the merge vs rebase

1. All branches (master, staging, feature) are rebased from production
2. Feature branch is always merged into the required stage
3. Feature branch is merged into higher sensitive stage only when that code is stable at lower sensitive stage

Steps are:

(keep production copy up to date)

```
git checkout production
git pull --rebase
```

(always rebase feature branch on production)

```
git checkout feature-branch
git pull --rebase
git rebase production
```

(always rebase testing branch on production, merge feature branch for developer testing)

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git rebase production
git merge feature-branch
```

(when developer testing is successful, always rebase staging branch on production, merge feature branch for user acceptance)

```
git checkout staging
git pull --rebase
git rebase production
git merge feature-branch
```

(when approved at user acceptance, merge feature-branch into production)

```
git checkout production
git pull --rebase
git merge feature-branch
```

There may be more optimized steps for accomplishing this.
We definitely look forward to hear about a better alternative.